# select tow row same time in one table

Tags: php, sql-server

I have this table:

```
USERID  CHECKTIME                CHECKTYPE
1       2018-10-21 09:01:08.000  I
1       2018-10-21 10:00:51.000  I
1       2018-10-22 13:19:23.000  1
1       2018-10-22 15:56:11.000  0
1       2018-10-22 16:51:27.000  O
```

I need select two rows like this:

```
userid   in                         out
1        2018-10-22 13:19:23.000    2018-10-22 15:56:11.000
```

but same the date and same userid 
date and userid come from post page php
database is sqlserver connection with php

```
SELECT TOP 1 checktime, userid, checktype
FROM CHECKINOUT 
WHERE userid = '$idd' 
    AND CAST(checktime As DATE)='$x'
    AND checktype='1' 
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 checktime, userid, checktype
FROM CHECKINOUT 
WHERE userid='$idd'
    AND CAST(checktime As DATE)='$x'
    AND checktype='0'
```

Comment: What's your expect result logic?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do the Check Types `I`, `1`,`0`, and `O` represent and how relate to your expected result?

Comment: im edit the qustion plz check

Comment: So in is max checktime per user where checktype is 1 and out is max checktime per user where checktype is 0?

Answer (score 0):

### Table structure

USERID : int(11)

CHECKTIME : datetime

CHECKTYPE : char(2)

### Query

```
SELECT USERID, MAX(`IN`) AS 'IN', MAX(`OUT`) AS 'OUT'
 FROM
(
    SELECT USERID
         , CASE WHEN CHECKTYPE = '1' THEN CHECKTIME ELSE '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000' END AS 'IN'
         , CASE WHEN CHECKTYPE = '0' THEN CHECKTIME ELSE '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000' END AS 'OUT'
    FROM CHECKINOUT
     WHERE CHECKTYPE IN ('0', '1')
) U
 GROUP BY U.USERID
```

I checked in my local and this query worked well.

### Explanation

#### Sub query `U`

It collect CHECKTIME for IN, and OUT by CHECKTYPE condition. When no IN data, the default value will be "0000:00:00 ....", and OUT is also.

#### In outer query

It will get max value (reject "0000:00:00 ..."), and group records, so we can get correct data.

I suggest using `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`, because it makes Query run faster than `DISTINCT`.

Comment: How `CheckType` can be `INT` and `String` in the same time?

Comment: `WHERE 1 `? That isn't a complete boolean expression.

Comment: It will throw `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'I' to data type int` error message.

Comment: @Sami, My data structure is : USERID (int), CHECKTIME(datetime), CHECKTYPE(char{2}). I do not know DB structure of the questioner, but with my DB structure, it worked well.

Comment: @Larnu, in Mysql, `WHERE 1` is accepted, meaning similar to condition true. This is my personal writing query.

Comment: Yes, but this is SQL Server, not MySQL. You've change the `WHERE 1` to `WHERE 1 = 1` now, which means the SQL will compile, but there's no need for the `1 =1`, as it'll always be true; calculating that `1 = 1` is simply a waste of the compiler's time.

Comment: @Larnu, you are right. I also said that is my personal writing. The reason is: if there are 1 or 2 more conditions in where, when I want to comment-out those conditions, then next to add more conditions,... I do not need to delete `WHERE`. **This way is useful for debugging** (as my own idea.)

Comment: Comment out the `WHERE`? I've seen `WHERE 1 = 1` plenty of times before your answer here, but it's still not really a good idea to have it there; as like i said it just waste's the compilers time.

Comment: I deleted "1 = 1" in Where

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([UserId] int, [CheckDate] datetime, [CheckType] BIT)
;

INSERT INTO T
    ([UserId], [CheckDate], [CheckType])
VALUES
    (1, '2018-10-21 09:01:08', 1),
    (1, '2018-10-21 10:00:51', 1),
    (1, '2018-10-22 13:19:23', 1),
    (1, '2018-10-22 15:56:11', 0),
    (1, '2018-10-22 16:51:27', 0)
;

SELECT DISTINCT UserID,
       (SELECT MAX(CheckDate) FROM T WHERE CheckType = 1 ANDUserID = TT.UserID) [In],
       (SELECT MIN(CheckDate) FROM T WHERE CheckType = 0 AND UserID = TT.UserID) [Out]
FROM T TT
WHERE UserID = 1;
```

You have wrong data in your sample (I guess), cause in your query you check for `'1'` and `'0'` in your query, which mean there is no `'I'`, so you can use `BIT` datatype instead of `VARCHAR`.

If you really have `'I'` in the check type so it would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID,
       (SELECT MAX(CheckDate) FROM T WHERE CheckType = '1' AND UserID = TT.UserID) [In],
       (SELECT MIN(CheckDate) FROM T WHERE CheckType = '0' AND UserID = TT.UserID) [Out]
FROM T TT
WHERE UserID = 1;
```

**Results**

```
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| UserID |         In          |         Out         |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
|      1 | 22/10/2018 13:19:23 | 22/10/2018 15:56:11 |
+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: @mickmackusa According to the OP query, I think `I` is a typo, still mybe it's `I`.

Comment: how can echo this table in php

Comment: @NaderAlqrabawi Well, that's another question :)